# Is there a name for the number of edges that need to be removed to lower the genus of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, topological-graph-theory

The number of edges that need to be removed from a graph to disconnect it is called the **edge-connectivity**. Similarly, given a graph of [genus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding#Terminology) $n>0$, there is a minimum number of edges that you have to remove to obtain a graph of genus $n-1$. Is there a name for this number?

Comment: Not as far as I know, and I've been doing this stuff for a long time. It's an interesting question, although I suspect that unless you put some more restrictions on the graphs to be considered you won't get any kind of nice answer.

Comment: @RickDecker I was thinking that an alternative definition would focus on embeddings. Thus, given an embedding of genus $n$ (not necessarily a minimum genus embedding), I could ask for the minimum number of edges that need to be removed from the embedding to obtain an embedding of genus $n-1$. I am asking a related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/156182/10063)